# Getting Error 0 when plotting boxplot of a filtered dataset

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I am working on the [Kaggle: Abalone dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/rodolfomendes/abalone-dataset) and I am facing a weird problem when plotting a boxplot.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/abalone/abalone.data', header=None)
df.columns = ['sex', 'Length', 'Diameter', 'Height', 'Whole weight', 'Shucked weight', 'Viscera weight', 'Shell weight', 'rings']
```

If a run:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(16,6))
plt.subplot(121)
sns.boxplot(data=df['rings'])
```

working perfectly!

If I filter the dataset by sex like this:

```
df_f = df[df['sex']=='F']
df_m = df[df['sex']=='M']
df_i = df[df['sex']=='I']
```

`df_f = (1307,9)`, `df_m=(1528,9)` and `df_i=(1342,9)`

And I run:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(16,6))
plt.subplot(121)
sns.boxplot(data=df_m['rings'])
```

working perfectly!

But if I run the code above for `df_f` and `df_i` datasets I get an error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3360             try:
-> 3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_434828/3363262611.py in <module>
----> 1 sns.boxplot(data=df_f['Rings'])

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/seaborn/_decorators.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     44             )
     45         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 46         return f(**kwargs)
     47     return inner_f
     48 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/seaborn/categorical.py in boxplot(x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order, orient, color, palette, saturation, width, dodge, fliersize, linewidth, whis, ax, **kwargs)
   2241 ):
   2242 
-> 2243     plotter = _BoxPlotter(x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order,
   2244                           orient, color, palette, saturation,
   2245                           width, dodge, fliersize, linewidth)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/seaborn/categorical.py in __init__(self, x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order, orient, color, palette, saturation, width, dodge, fliersize, linewidth)
    404                  width, dodge, fliersize, linewidth):
    405 
--> 406         self.establish_variables(x, y, hue, data, orient, order, hue_order)
    407         self.establish_colors(color, palette, saturation)
    408 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/seaborn/categorical.py in establish_variables(self, x, y, hue, data, orient, order, hue_order, units)
     96                 if hasattr(data, "shape"):
     97                     if len(data.shape) == 1:
---> 98                         if np.isscalar(data[0]):
     99                             plot_data = [data]
    100                         else:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    940 
    941         elif key_is_scalar:
--> 942             return self._get_value(key)
    943 
    944         if is_hashable(key):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in _get_value(self, label, takeable)
   1049 
   1050         # Similar to Index.get_value, but we do not fall back to positional
-> 1051         loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
   1052         return self.index._get_values_for_loc(self, loc, label)
   1053 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:
-> 3363                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3364 
   3365         if is_scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans:

KeyError: 0
```

There's no missing values, all values are int.

What am I missing here?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71423584/7758804) should be the accepted answer, since it actually answers the question of **What am I missing**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is addressed in Seaborn 0.13.  Here is a workaround for older versions. In any case, it is encouraged to use the `x=` or `y=` parameters instead of `data=` (by default, the first parameter would be `data`).

You seem to have encountered a bug. In this case, the last code inside seaborn is important. At [line 447 in categorical.py](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/069d53a3dd29a965987705c823883a93700bbe5e/seaborn/categorical.py#L447), there is a test `if np.isscalar(data[0])` with `data = df_f['rings']`. As data now is a pandas Series, index position 0 is tested, but this index isn't in the selection.

To further investigate the problem, it helps to try to reproduce it with a minimal example:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Sex': ['M', 'M', 'F', 'F'],
                   'Rings': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
df_m = df[df['Sex'] == 'M']
df_f = df[df['Sex'] == 'F']
sns.boxplot(data=df_f['Rings'])
```

This does reproduce the error.

A workaround is to only pass the values to the seaborn function:

```py
sns.boxplot(data=df_f['Rings'].values)
```

Or to use the dataframe as `data` and the column as `y`:

```py
sns.boxplot(data=df_f, y='Rings')
```

As the bug is inside `seaborn/categorical.py`, similar functions will run into the same problem.

See also [issue 2756](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2756) at seaborn's github.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a box plot per value of a categorical column I suggest:

```py
sns.boxplot(data=df, x='rings', y='sex')
```